# Why does Yii2 save files as different owner/group between console and frontend/backend applications

Tags: amazon-ec2, yii2

I am using Yii2 in AWS EC2.
Ive noticed while using the yii2 framework, if I save a file in the console application, it saves at as the instance owner/group ec2-user.  When using the frontend/backend application it get saved as apache owner/group.

In itself is not a problem unless I try to access the file from the opposing application I get a permission error.

I am guessing since the console is started from the crond, it is using the ec2-user where as the other applications are being served by apache.

What would be the best way to handle file access owned by another or can I set either application to run as a different user/group.

Thanks

I used the same function for each application,
fopen('file/path.txt','wb+');

I searched the framework site and internet for solutions, but no luck or not asking correctly

Comment: Maybe, try running the `cron` job with `apache` user

Comment: Thanks, I had not even considered that for whatever reason.